# Finding whether a point lies inside or outside a curve on the parametric domain

Tags: parametric

I have a parametric surface and a curve in the parametric domain of that surface (let's say u and v), and findally a point somewhere on that surface at parameters u and v. How do I determine if that point is within the curve or not?

Comment: It depends on what the curve is, as for example if it's circle than when you substitute (u,v) and if equation is >0 it lie outside the circle, if it's <0 then inside and if =0 then on it. But as long as I remember only in case of hyperbola it's opposite and all other cases follow the former thing.

Comment: For quadrics you can use the polar hyperplane of the point.